# Python to parse non-standard XML file

Tags: python, xml-parsing

My input file is actually multiple XML files appending to one file. (It's from [Google Patents](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/patents/grantbib/2011/ipgb20110104_wk01.zip)). It has below structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE us-patent-grant SYSTEM "us-patent-grant.dtd" [ ]>
<root_node>...</root_node>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE us-patent-grant SYSTEM "us-patent-grant.dtd" [ ]>
<root_node>...</root_node>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE us-patent-grant SYSTEM "us-patent-grant.dtd" [ ]>
<root_node>...</root_node>
```

Python xml.dom.minidom can't parse this non-standard file. What's a better way to parse this file? I am not below code has good performance or not.

```
for line in infile:
  if line == '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>': 
    xmldoc = minidom.parse(XMLstring)
  else:
    XMLstring += line
```

Comment: I downloaded and extracted the zip archive you give in link. I obtained three files: **ipgb20110104.xml** , **ipgb20110104rpt.html** , **ipgb20110104lst.txt** . I found the above extract in none of these three files. Where does your extract come from ? - Also, what kind of exploitation do you want to do of the extract ?

Comment: @eyquem, it's in the xml file. I just replaced "us-patent-grant" node to "root_node" to make the structure more clear.

Comment: Thank you. I had understood for the line **<root_node>...</root_node>** but I wonder the hell how I didn't for the other line; i searched for it too superficially, I think

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my take on it, using a generator and `lxml.etree`. Extracted information purely for example.

```
import urllib2, os, zipfile
from lxml import etree

def xmlSplitter(data,separator=lambda x: x.startswith('<?xml')):
  buff = []
  for line in data:
    if separator(line):
      if buff:
        yield ''.join(buff)
        buff[:] = []
    buff.append(line)
  yield ''.join(buff)

def first(seq,default=None):
  """Return the first item from sequence, seq or the default(None) value"""
  for item in seq:
    return item
  return default

datasrc = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/patents/grantbib/2011/ipgb20110104_wk01.zip"
filename = datasrc.split('/')[-1]

if not os.path.exists(filename):
  with open(filename,'wb') as file_write:
    r = urllib2.urlopen(datasrc)
    file_write.write(r.read())

zf = zipfile.ZipFile(filename)
xml_file = first([ x for x in zf.namelist() if x.endswith('.xml')])
assert xml_file is not None

count = 0
for item in xmlSplitter(zf.open(xml_file)):
  count += 1
  if count > 10: break
  doc = etree.XML(item)
  docID = "-".join(doc.xpath('//publication-reference/document-id/*/text()'))
  title = first(doc.xpath('//invention-title/text()'))
  assignee = first(doc.xpath('//assignee/addressbook/orgname/text()'))
  print "DocID:    {0}\nTitle:    {1}\nAssignee: {2}\n".format(docID,title,assignee)
```

Yields:

```
DocID:    US-D0629996-S1-20110104
Title:    Glove backhand
Assignee: Blackhawk Industries Product Group Unlimited LLC

DocID:    US-D0629997-S1-20110104
Title:    Belt sleeve
Assignee: None

DocID:    US-D0629998-S1-20110104
Title:    Underwear
Assignee: X-Technology Swiss GmbH

DocID:    US-D0629999-S1-20110104
Title:    Portion of compression shorts
Assignee: Nike, Inc.

DocID:    US-D0630000-S1-20110104
Title:    Apparel
Assignee: None

DocID:    US-D0630001-S1-20110104
Title:    Hooded shirt
Assignee: None

DocID:    US-D0630002-S1-20110104
Title:    Hooded shirt
Assignee: None

DocID:    US-D0630003-S1-20110104
Title:    Hooded shirt
Assignee: None

DocID:    US-D0630004-S1-20110104
Title:    Headwear cap
Assignee: None

DocID:    US-D0630005-S1-20110104
Title:    Footwear
Assignee: Vibram S.p.A.
```

Comment: I posted a version using generators, but looks like you beat me to it. +1

Comment: @MattH How did you know the address **h t t p://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/patents/grantbib/2011/ipgb20110104_wk01.zip** , please ?

Comment: @MattH I didn't even think to make "Copy the shortcut" on the hyper-link ! Thank you. Your code is clean, I upvote

Answer (score 2):

I'd opt for parsing each chunk of XML separately.

You seem to already be doing that in your sample code. Here's my take on your code:

```
def parse_xml_buffer(buffer):
    dom = minidom.parseString("".join(buffer))  # join list into string of XML
    # .... parse dom ...

buffer = [file.readline()]  # initialise with the first line
for line in file:
    if line.startswith("<?xml "):
        parse_xml_buffer(buffer)
        buffer = []  # reset buffer
    buffer.append(line)  # list operations are faster than concatenating strings
parse_xml_buffer(buffer)  # parse final chunk
```

Once you've broken the file down to individual XML blocks, how you actually do the parsing depends on your requirements and, to some extent, your preference. Options are [lxml](http://lxml.de/), [minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html), [elementtree](http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm), [expat](http://docs.python.org/library/pyexpat.html), [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), etc.

---

#### Update:

Starting from scratch, here's how I would do it (using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

def separated_xml(infile):
    file = open(infile, "r")
    buffer = [file.readline()]
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith("<?xml "):
            yield "".join(buffer)
            buffer = []
        buffer.append(line)
    yield "".join(buffer)
    file.close()

for xml_string in separated_xml("ipgb20110104.xml"):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_string)
    for num in soup.findAll("doc-number"):
        print num.contents[0]
```

This returns:

```
D0629996
29316765
D471343
D475175
6715152
D498899
D558952
D571528
D577177
D584027
.... (lots more)...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about minidom, nor much about XML parsing, but I have used XPath to parse XML/HTML. E.g. within the [lxml module](http://lxml.de/).

Here you can find some XPath Examples: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_examples.asp

Comment: The crucial point is that the input files are *nonstandard* (malformed) Xml files; in particular, several Xml documents in a single file. Is that supported by lxml?