# Parsing XPath within non standard XML using lxml Python

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

I’m trying to create a database of all patent information from Google Patents. Much of my work so far has been using this very good answer from MattH in [Python to parse non-standard XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7336718).   My Python is too large to display so its linked [here](http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=CDEZq).

The source files [are here](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/patents/grant_full_text/2010/ipg100105.zip): 
a bunch of xml files appended together into one file with multiple headers.The issue is trying to use the correct xpath expression when parsing this unsual "non-standard" XML file which has multiple xml and dtd declarations. I have been trying to use `"-".join(doc.xpath` to tie everything together when its parsed out but the output creates blanks separated by hyphens for the `<document-id>` and `<classification-national>` shown below

```
<references-cited> <citation> 
<patcit num="00001"> <document-id>
<country>US</country> 
<doc-number>534632</doc-number> 
<kind>A</kind>
<name>Coleman</name> 
<date>18950200</date> 
</document-id> </patcit>
<category>cited by examiner</category>
<classification-national><country>US</country>
<main-classification>249127</main-classification></classification-national>
</citation>
```

**Note** not all children exist within each `<citation>`, sometimes they are not present at all.

How can I parse this xpath while trying to place hyphens between each data entry for multiple entries under `<citation>` ?

Comment: Please trim down your question. If I understand you, the problem is building a correct XPath expression with Python.

Comment: I've edited the question again for ease to read.

Answer (score 1):

From this XML (references.xml),

```
<references-cited> 
  <citation> 
    <patcit num="00001"> 
      <document-id>
        <country>US</country> 
        <doc-number>534632</doc-number> 
        <kind>A</kind>
        <name>Coleman</name> 
        <date>18950200</date> 
      </document-id> 
    </patcit>
    <category>cited by examiner</category>
    <classification-national>
      <country>US</country>
      <main-classification>249127</main-classification>
    </classification-national>
  </citation>

  <citation>
    <patcit num="00002">
      <document-id>
        <country>US</country>
        <doc-number>D28957</doc-number>
        <kind>S</kind>
        <name>Simon</name>
        <date>18980600</date>
      </document-id>
    </patcit>
    <category>cited by other</category>
  </citation>
</references-cited>
```

you can get the text content of every descendant of `<citation>` that has any content as follows:

```
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse("references.xml")
cits = doc.xpath('/references-cited/citation')

for c in cits:
    descs = c.xpath('.//*')
    for d in descs:
        if d.text and d.text.strip():
            print "%s: %s"  %(d.tag, d.text)
    print
```

Output:

```
country: US
doc-number: 534632
kind: A
name: Coleman
date: 18950200
category: cited by examiner
country: US
main-classification: 249127

country: US
doc-number: D28957
kind: S
name: Simon
date: 18980600
category: cited by other
```

This variation:

```
import sys
from lxml import etree

doc = etree.parse("references.xml")
cits = doc.xpath('/references-cited/citation')

for c in cits:
    descs = c.xpath('.//*')
    for d in descs:
        if d.text and d.text.strip():
            sys.stdout.write("-%s"  %(d.text))
    print
```

results in this output:

```
-US-534632-A-Coleman-18950200-cited by examiner-US-249127
-US-D28957-S-Simon-18980600-cited by other
```

Comment: I'm sensing we are close but this method didn't yield any output when I tried it. I have editted my question above to properly explain further my issue.

Comment: Did you try my example exactly as it is, or did you try to use my Python code on another XML document?

Comment: I used it on another XML. Just the last 4 lines you gave me starting at descs = doc.xpath

Comment: I believe the reason there is an issue is because the xml I'm using is based in a .zip and has multiple xml declarations within it. It just this way with this file type which is why the python created by MattH cited at the top was able to parse through. Also when the xml was edited properly your python ran completely as is but no output was printed within the shell or in a separate file

Comment: Your question was about an XPath problem. You can't evaluate XPath expressions on "non-standard" XML. My example works.

Comment: You are right it does work- I had to edit down my file to only what you were requesting of it. But I'm looking for a way to parse out citations into a text file with hyphens separating each bit of data

Comment: I believe you might have stated this with "You can't evaluate XPath expressions on "non-standard" XML" but can you run an xpath expression within the example provided [here??](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335560/python-to-parse-non-standard-xml-file/7336718#7336718) 
Well this is really close to the output I'm looking for outside the fact that its using locally sourced xml and not non standard xml from .zip files that I have.