# Appropriate xpath syntax with python for non-standard xml

Tags: python, xml, xpath

The input file is actually multiple XML files appending to one file. (Sourced from [Google Patents](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/patents/grant_full_text/2010/ipg100105.zip)). This is an example:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!DOCTYPE us-patent-grant SYSTEM "us-patent-grant-v42-2006-08-23.dtd" [ ]>
> <us-patent-grant lang="EN" dtd-version="v4.2 2006-08-23">
> <applicants>
> <applicant sequence="001" app-type="applicant-inventor" designation="us-only">
> <addressbook><last-name>Beyer</last-name>
> <first-name>Daniel Lee</first-name>
> <address><city>Franklin</city>
> <state>TN</state>
> <country>US</country></address></addressbook>
> <nationality><country>omitted</country></nationality>
> <residence><country>US</country></residence>
> </applicant>
> <applicant sequence="002" app-type="applicant-inventor" designation="us-only">
> <addressbook><last-name>Friedland</last-name>
> <first-name>Jason Michael</first-name>
> <address><city>Franklin</city>
> <state>TN</state>
> <country>US</country></address></addressbook>
> <nationality><country>omitted</country></nationality>
> <residence><country>US</country></residence>
> </applicant>
> </applicants>
> </us-patent-grant>
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!DOCTYPE us-patent-grant SYSTEM "us-patent-grant-v42-2006-08-23.dtd" [ ]>
> ```

I'm trying to create a string with a `"-".join` xpath for all of the children and grandchildren within `<applicant>` using the following in python with lxml:

```
import urllib2, os, zipfile
from lxml import etree
count = 0
for item in xmlSplitter(zf.open(xml_file)):
  count += 1
  if count > 1: break
  doc = etree.XML(item)
  docID = "-".join(doc.xpath('//publication-reference/document-id/*/text()'))
  title = first(doc.xpath('//invention-title/text()'))
  applicant = "-".join(doc.xpath('//applicants/applicant/*/text()'))
  print "DocID:    {0}\nTitle:    {1}\nApplicant: {2}\n".format(docID,title,applicant)
  outFile.write(str(docID) +"|"+ str(title) +"|"+ str(applicant) +"\n")
```

I've tried mutliple [xpath combinations](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) but I can't produce a string with hyphens for `<applicants>` and while */*/text() cant get to the grandchild it doesn't help with the stringing. What is the appropriate xpath syntax to select all text within the children and grandchildren of `<applicant>` and still punch it out in a string? While not shown in this example is there a way to ignore unicode that might be present at the beginning of a text line too (I believe it appears in some of the later xml docs)?  The 'applicant' output I'm hoping to get should look something like:

```
Beyer-Daniel Lee-Franklin-TN-US-omitted-US-Friedland-Jason Michael-Franklin-TN-US-omitted-US
```

Comment: I tried this xpath `//applicants/applicant/*/*/text()| //applicants/applicant/addressbook/address/*/text()` and my output is   `'Beyer-Daniel Lee-Franklin-TN-US-omitted-US-Friedland-Jason Michael-Franklin-TN-US-omitted-US'`. Is this your desired output.

Comment: Yes and no, at least in the way my output looks. Did you connect together your output? my output consisted `|Roskam-Cameron O.- -Grand Rapids- -MI- -US- -omitted-US|` with returns and these extra hyphens. Is there a way to get it to fit into the string seemlessly?

Comment: didn't get `Did you connect together your output?`.

Comment: I generated this output from the sample xml snippet you provided. My code http://pastebin.com/eAz2Cq19

Comment: I meant did you manually edit together your output but looking at your code it isn't the same as mine in the example. I guess I will have to adjust my python from `doc = etree.XML(item)` to `et = etree.parse('test.xml')`? I used `applicant = "-".join(doc.xpath('//applicants/applicant/*/*/text()| //applicants/applicant/addressbook/address/*/text()'))` exactly in my provided python was thinking it would work the same but it came out clunky, not clean like yours.

Comment: Did your output result from using a 'parse' in `et = etree.parse` then a `'-'.join(value).replace('\n-','')` at the end to print it? Is this the only way to effectively parse out this or can what I've started be used?

Comment: I used `doc = etree.XML(item)` loaded the complete xml snippet you provided in into a string (`item`) and than used my xpath expr it worked fine.

Comment: So I tried it on my python with some adjustments and it worked! Here is the code I used to get the python I wanted: `value = doc.xpath('//applicants/applicant/*/*/text()|//applicants/applicant/addressbook/address/*/text()')
  value = '-'.join(value).replace('\n-','')`

Answer (score 0):

This question is very similar to [this other question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458110).

There are two problems here:

1. How to get from "non-standard XML" to "standard XML"?
2. How to use XPath to get text values of descendant elements and concatenate them?

You need to solve 1 before attacking 2. If you need help with that, ask a separate question.

"Non-standard XML" is the same as **not XML at all**. You can't parse it as XML, and you can't use XPath on it. But you have phrased the question in a way that makes it look like you are trying to do that anyway.

Assuming that your question is actually about working with "standard XML", how about using the same approach as in [my answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9471116/407651)?

Comment: There is no issue with your approach for standard xml; it works but my question is about non standard xml and how to parse through it. As was cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335560/python-to-parse-non-standard-xml-file/7336718#7336718) you can parse through non standard xml and use xpath in the same python process. I have used this python provided in that example to parse information from the children but not the grandchildren. The question I was asking was how to use xpath to read out the grandchildren text and still join and string out the information in order.

Comment: Also: the data source is as cited directly above from Google Patents- a non-standard xml file that consists of many xml files appended within 1 singular file. When I saw this at first glance I like others knew it needed to be adjusted to be parsed but there are two issues with editing this file. Its extremely large (430 MB) and two each xml has unique xml-style codes for the `<us-patent-grant>` which includes unique number codes (around 5000 per file) to which I can't select within file editing programs such as Notepad++. Editing 1000+ files manually isnt needed when python can just parse it

Comment: You have to make it easier for other people to help you. If you are having trouble turning "non-standard XML" data files into parseable XML, please ask a new question **only about that**. Construct a trimmed-down [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the gist of the problem.